# как засунуть массив в параметр php pdo

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
$id_brand = [1,2,3]
brands.id_brand IN (:id_brand)
':id_brand' => (implode(',',$id_brand))
```

я пробовал так, но sql воспринимает как строку, то есть, одно значение.

```
[":id_brand"]=> string(5) "1,2,3"
```

Comment: чет все работает https://phpize.online/?phpses=ef710097070d8b746450df94df3e8b8a&sqlses=19ccb1a838bee7cdd6b168bfd8b77a42&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: @Jean-Claude [работает, говоришь](https://phpize.online/?phpses=add699d6d91fd58b99756a48e7a8d4b7)?  Серьёзно?

Comment: @Ипатьев да, в целом работает))

Comment: @Jean-Claude стыдно должно быть такой код писать, не говоря о том чтобы показывать другим людям